# Clear Frame Cache

Tags: c#, caching, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

How Can I clear Frame Cache in windows metro style app? I enabled the cache in the initialization

```
NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
```

I want to initialize new Frame without disabling the cache because I use it for another path.

Answer (score 0):

By override `OnNavigatedTo`

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
      if(condition == true)
      {
        this.InitializeComponent();
      }
    }
```

and clear all children in global static controls.

Comment: doesn't work for me.
I have a page that can take a parameter.
If it gets the parameter it renders something a little different.
With caching it renders the same when it doesn't get a parameter and calling `this.InitializeComponent();` does not fix it.